# Upgrade Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 still possible?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, windows-10-upgrade

I want upgrade my Windows, but I don't know if it's still possible?
And if it is possible, will I be able to fully erase my data (like formatting drive)?

Comment: Of course it's possible.  You will have to purchase a Windows 10 license.

Comment: You can give it a try. [Download Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/) and create a bootable USB flash disk using their tool. Then start the installer from that disk. If it doesn't ask you for product key, then you'll get a free upgrade without losing data (except for some programs which may be incompatible - Windows will warn you that these will be removed). If it asks for product key, then you have to buy Windows 10 to upgrade.

Comment: Oh, and you'll be given an option to perform a clean install too.

Answer (score 0):

No.

"The Windows 10 free upgrade through the Get Windows 10 (GWX) app ended on July 29, 2016."

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/12435/windows-10-upgrade-faq

Comment: "through the Get Windows 10 (GWX) app" is the key here. You can still use a Windows 10 installation media to upgrade. Or at least you could last month.

Comment: True, but the media alone is not a "free upgrade"

Comment: I don't get what you mean. You can download a Windows 10 ISO from Microsoft without paying or proving you own a license. It's the first Google result for "download windows". They provide a tool that will create a bootable flash drive with ISO's contents. Do that, run setup.exe, follow instructions, get a free upgrade.

Comment: You don't get a license with the ISO, surely the old win 8 serial isnt going to work when you try to activate the 10 install... is it?

Comment: It doesn't ask for product key. After the upgrade it gets a new one and activates successfully. I literally did that last month. I'm also pretty sure that Windows 10 installer accepted some Windows 8 keys in 2017 (for clean install, not upgrade). When I tried it recently it didn't work, but I don't know if they banned them in installer or if OEM keys never worked like that.

Comment: ok Interesting re the upgrade - I'll admit the last time I did an upgrade was win XP to Vista and that went quite badly, never have before or since, and never will!